# Hadoop on Azure examples resulting in a blank file

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Hadoop on Azure C# Streaming Sample Tutorial I was trying this out. I installed sample code on my account, and then when I tried to execute the job following output I get and end of the day a blank file is produced.. sometimes even that is not produced.
Following things I do see on my screen:
[image: First Screen]

has anybody faced this type of issue?

[image: second image]

Comment: Please share your Task Tracker log, this could contain more information about the error (like exit code).

Comment: I am very sorry ... How do I get that?? I am just trying to learn it.. It's my first day :(

Comment: Try here: c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\

Comment: I am using Windows azure directly.. So Should I RDP and see inside that?

Comment: c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\  has nothing.. and only
c:\hdfs\mapred\local\jobTracker\ exists and even it's empty

Comment: Try to look for log files in another folder / disk (I don't have access to HD Insight atm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My cluster was created on 29th of november. Microsoft posted BUG related to hadoop this on [THIS LINK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/hdinsight/thread/28a57efb-082b-424b-8d9e-731b1fe135de) So I did recreate my cluster and then my issues resolved. Even the basic examples given in SAMPLES where not working on that day. So Now everything is fine.. Thanks a lot.